# Access blocked: Authorization Error - Google Auth Supabase Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, google-oauth, supabase

I got error when implement supabase authentication using google provider in flutter. It says "Access blocked: Authorization Error". Is there any my mistake or the problem is from google? but another developer experience like me too using their third-party.

[image: Show error]

I have checked the credential and oauth screen in google cloud with supabase authentication, but there is no problem. From the code, i follow supabase_flutter documentation.

Comment: make sure your app is running https

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo with same code, last week i could login with google auth provider. But yesterday when i tried to run my code again, the problem appeared

Comment: Something isn't configured correctly in your Google console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before, i used flutter_appauth package for request access to google. Now, i change it with google_sign_in package and its working.